# Algorithm for drawing generalised circles

Tags: graphing-functions, computational-geometry, floating-point, inversive-geometry

A generalised circle is either a circle in the plane or a line. The general equation of one is:

$$A(x^2 + y^2) + Bx + Cy + D=0,$$

where $4AD - B^2 - C^2 \leq 0$. This can be checked by completing the square on $x$ and $y$, and checking that the minimum value of the LHS is $4AD - B^2 - C^2$.

My question is: What algorithm would you use to draw it?

Seems there are different approaches:

1. Break it into the circle case and line case. Draw each using a dedicated routine. This way, you can use pre-existing drawing routines. There is a problem here, which is that out of many possible floating point values, only one of them is exactly $0$. So the line case happens in one case out of $2^{64}$ (if you use $64$-bit floats). And on top of that, thanks to rounding errors, what *should* be a line can become a circle. The circle case requires finding the centre and radius, but these can both be large values, subject to floating-point rounding errors. You can use a threshold instead of checking whether $A = 0$, but which threshold should get used?
2. Traverse each value of $x$ in the viewport, and compute the (at most) $2$ different values of $y$, and draw those points. Then do the same again, but traversing each value of $y$ and finding $x$.
3. A generalised circle determines a constant-speed motion along it. Use this somehow.
4. A generalised circle determines an [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry) through it. Use this fact somehow.

Approach 2 explicitly uses the viewport. Approaches 3 and 4 are vague, but depend on knowing it as well.

What approaches are there?

Comment: Maybe I should ask this question in the computer graphics SE. I expect some low quality answers here, probably based on approach 1.

Comment: I posted it as well onto https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/13025/algorithm-for-drawing-generalised-circles . I don't know whether it's appropriate there either. Is this a Computer Science question? I don't know if I should cross-post to the CS SE as well.

Comment: The [Midpoint circle algorith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to generate a raster image of the circle, since you are considering the viewport.

Given that, I think you're focusing on the wrong thing: If you have the viewport, you can just check if each coordinate satisfies the equation. The point is, if your A goes to zero, the 'other end' of the circle might not even be in the viewport(you don't have to 'treat' it differently). The main problem is, the pixels in the viewport might not even have a few floating point coordinates that satisfy the equation(that's where you'd need a threshold):[image: Low threshold]

Increasing the margin of error would give you this:

[image: High threshold]

I've made a small shader toy for this: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/7tVBDV

You can change it/tell me if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work when $A = 0$.

Comment: It plots something when $A$ is small, but is pitch black when $A = 0$.

Comment: Works better when I increase the threshold. I guess your pixel shader runs much faster than my Pygame code. I've used my approach number 2 which is faster than your approach (which goes through every single pixel in the viewport) and it's already really slow. Also, I haven't made the mistake you accused me of. I *know* that when $A = 0$, almost all of the line is outside of the screen. I don't know how you assumed I didn't know this.

Comment: The lesson from this answer is that I should use a pixel shader if I want speed. The programming is easier too, because you can just compute $A(x^2 + y^2) + Bx + Cy + D$ for each $(x,y)$ coordinate in the viewport. That's something I've personally never done.

Comment: @wlad I'm just saying you wouldn't need to calculate two values, or a dedicated routine, etc.. Any curve will do. And you can use your cpu for the same thing(in a for loop: integrating shaders can be a pain).

Comment: If you program in Python or Matlab, the algorithm above can be vectorised. This should make it reasonably fast for many use cases.

Answer (score 1):

- For each pixel in the image:

  - For each corner $(x,y)$ of the pixel (imagining the image as a small square tiling), compute the sign of $A(x^2+y^2)+Bx+Cy+D$.
  - If all the signs are the same, plot the background colour.
  - If any of the signs differ, plot the foreground colour.

See https://www.shadertoy.com/view/NlGBWt for a live WebGL-based example.  There is a slight thickening artifact for certain parameters, when the curve gives a sign of exactly $0$ for many pixel corner coordinates.

Comment: Interesting. You can vectorise this algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: Is it useful to do this hierarchically? Test every 16x16 block of pixels and proceed to 4x4 blocks or individual pixels only if not rejected? (Basis is of course that the function is convex, so that the properties of the corner points apply also to their convex hull.)

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't think so, at least not without more work: the sign can be the same for all corners but a small circle could be inside or cross an edge twice etc.  But you can do that kind of optimisation if you have (bounds on) a signed distance function - this could make a nice additional answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This only works for blocks that are totally inside.